# HighChart- When I use useUTC: false then x axis data are not showing properly

Tags: react-native, highcharts

I have created a line chart of date-time. In that want to display some other time zone dates on X-Axis. For this, I am setting up

```
time: {
   useUTC: false
}
```

Then X-axis values are not showing properly. I have also set X-axis type

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
```

Jsfiddle Link:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/chetanpatil1993/q3jksh1n/1/
2. https://jsfiddle.net/chetanpatil1993/jd8L7tv6/2/
3. https://jsfiddle.net/chetanpatil1993/cz2tbenp/4/

I am using the same config in react native. But also find similar issue

Output graph:

[image]

Please help me out

Comment: Hi @Chetan Patil, What do you exactly mean by `X-axis values are not showing properly`? Could you describe the problem more precisely?

Comment: @ppotaczek On X-Axis label is not showing properly some time there is no label or only one label. We have proper data series this issue occurs only when we use "useUTC: false" in our code. You can also check the JSfiddle link for the same. I am also adding output garph image in this question.

Comment: Thanks for the explonation. Labels are shown in the all jsfiddle links. Does your problem occur only in React Native?

Comment: In react-native but for cross-checking I have tried in JSfiddle but the same occurs.

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to reproduce the problem. As I already said every example that you provided works fine.

Comment: But I am facing the same issue. for more reference can you pls go through this high chart support thread. link: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=45539
I have tried every possible solution But not able to fix this issue from last couple of days.
Graph Screenshot: https://imgur.com/eB5hKT1

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was be able to reproduce the problem after changing system time-zone to Indian. I see that you already reported a bug here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14824, so please continue the discussion in the github thread.

Comment: @ppotaczek had this issue resolved yet? I faced same issue like this.

Comment: Hi @Hien Nguyen, The issue is closed, but it doesn't seem to be fixed. Could you add a comment in the GitHub thread?