# Highchart xAxis and value did not align

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have highchart series with time, I try to configure as below

http://jsfiddle.net/viethien/3eofd1nk/33/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
                },
           chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                type:'area',
                plotBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                backgroundColor:'transparent',
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'X Axis and value not match',
                align: 'left',
                margin: 30,
                style:{
                    fontFamily:'VegurRegular',
                    fontSize:'21px'
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text:'Date Time',
                align: 'left',
                x: 20,
                style: {
                    color: '#282828',
                    fontFamily:'VegurRegular'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                type: 'datetime',
                labels : {
                    formatter: function() {
var myDate = new Date(this.value);
var newDateMs = Date.UTC(myDate.getUTCFullYear(),myDate.getUTCMonth()-1,myDate.getUTCDate());   
return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',newDateMs);      
                    },
                    style:{
                        fontFamily:'VegurRegular'
                    }
                 }
            },
            yAxis: {
                opposite:true,    
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                 
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return [this.value];
                    },
                    style:{
                        fontFamily:'VegurRegular'
                    }

                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                formatter: function() {
var myDate = new Date(this.x);                        
var newDateMs = Date.UTC(myDate.getUTCFullYear(),myDate.getUTCMonth()-1,myDate.getUTCDate());   
return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',newDateMs);    
                    
                 },
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
            stops: [
              [0, '#5cc2d6'],
              [1, Highcharts.color('#5cc2d6').setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
            ]
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },
    
            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data:  [{x: 1628175600000, y: 15.06670830384981064, display: "2021-08-06"},
                      {x: 1628262000000, y: 10.9409600143487062, display: "2021-08-07"},
                      {x: 1628348400000, y: 50.5110465749795092, display: "2021-08-08"},
                      {x: 1628434800000, y: 30.5244073812182639, display: "2021-08-09"},
                      {x: 1628521200000, y: 20.7439211283888343, display: "2021-08-10"},
                      {x: 1628607600000, y: 60.6684340924556529, display: "2021-08-11"},
                      {x: 1628694000000, y: 90.5417027025304146, display: "2021-08-12"}]
            }]
        });
    });
```

[image]

I  read other article and suggest set utc false but not work.

[HighChart- When I use useUTC: false then x axis data are not showing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65286376/highchart-when-i-use-useutc-false-then-x-axis-data-are-not-showing-properly)

Could you help me this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `tickPositioner` function and generate ticks in the same positions as points.

```
  tickPositioner: function() {
    return this.series[0].xData;
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/43bugf76/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner

Answer (score 1):

Highchart is doing everything right. Once you remove the `formatter` from both the XAxis Label and Tooltip, you will see that the Timestamps from your dataset are not actually from 00:00 clock.

[image]

I see two ways around this, either convert the `x` UNIX Timestamp from your dataset to display the date only, or change your Highchart configuration to use the `display` from your dataset as the XAxis.

The code example below includes the function `shiftTimeInData` to convert the dataset and to align the `x` with your `display`.

I also modified your `formatter`.

```
function shiftTimeInData(data){
    $(data).each(function(){
        let d = new Date(this.x);
        this.x = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()+1);
    });
    return data;
}

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
       chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            type:'area',
            plotBackgroundColor: '#fff',
            backgroundColor:'transparent',
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'X Axis and value not match',
            align: 'left',
            margin: 30,
            style:{
                fontFamily:'VegurRegular',
                fontSize:'21px'
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
            text:'Date Time',
            align: 'left',
            x: 20,
            style: {
                color: '#282828',
                fontFamily:'VegurRegular'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            formatter: function() {
                  return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.value);
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            labels : {
                
                style:{
                    fontFamily:'VegurRegular'
                },
                align:'left'
             }
        },
        yAxis: {
            opposite:true,    
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
             
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return [this.value];
                },
                style:{
                    fontFamily:'VegurRegular'
                }

            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
        stops: [
          [0, '#5cc2d6'],
          [1, Highcharts.color('#5cc2d6').setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data:  shiftTimeInData([{x: 1628175600000, y: 15.06670830384981064, display: "2021-08-06"},
                  {x: 1628262000000, y: 10.9409600143487062, display: "2021-08-07"},
                  {x: 1628348400000, y: 50.5110465749795092, display: "2021-08-08"},
                  {x: 1628434800000, y: 30.5244073812182639, display: "2021-08-09"},
                  {x: 1628521200000, y: 20.7439211283888343, display: "2021-08-10"},
                  {x: 1628607600000, y: 60.6684340924556529, display: "2021-08-11"},
                  {x: 1628694000000, y: 90.5417027025304146, display: "2021-08-12"}])
        }]
    });
});
```

As you can see, the function `shiftTimeInData` is called right when adding the data it to the Highchart series.